# Build failed after installing and configuring react-native-fbsdk

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, build, react-native-fbsdk, illegal-characters

I have initialized a new android project and I installed react-native-fbsdk on my project, after doing all the necessary configuration steps provided in the [github page](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk), [facebook getting started page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/), and the [quick start for android page](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android) I am not able to run my project, even without writing any code. (I've tried with and without modifying the first two build.gradle steps)

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
> Task :react-native-fbsdk:generateDebugRFile FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:generateDebugRFile'.
> Illegal char <?> at index 7: ..\..\l?brary_man?fest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with
Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:comm
and_line_warnings

BU?LD FAILED in 3s
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag
for more details.
```

Heres what I have tried so far:

```
cd android
gradlew build --warning-mode all
```

Gives me an error message similar to the previous one, only difference is there is this line

```
Changing the value for a property with a final value has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 6.0.
```

I couldn't reach a solution researching this.

Then I have tried looking into the android manifest in D:\kitapapp\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build\intermediates\lıbrary_manıfest\debug , but I couldn't do anything with it either. It occurred to me that maybe it is related to the "lıbrary_manıfest" folder having "ı"s in it's name instead of "i"s but there were other files in the same folder as "lıbrary_manıfest" that also had "ı"s in their name. I don't think I can get pretty far modyfing react-native-fbsdk anyway since I'm supposed to use them? (but maybe I am wrong?)

I have also tried downgrading react-native-fbsdk in my package.json and deleting node_modules and npm installing again, gave me the same error message.

Edit: AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.kitapapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity 
android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml (I've put "id" here instead of the real id for this post. In reality there is my actual app id there)

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">kitapapp</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">id</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please upload your AndroidManifest.xml data

Comment: @GáüřãvJõşhï I added it now

Comment: @GáüřãvJõşhï is it that am I supposed to put my actual application id in the manifest? My thought process was that since there were already things like 'android:label' had value "@string/app_name" instead of the actual app name I'm not supposed to put my actual id. None of the installation/configuration guides I have linked also don't spesifically mention about such a thing?

Comment: goto /android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml and upload the data in the xml

Comment: @GáüřãvJõşhï ok i have done it but I've omitted putting my actual id in the post.

Comment: P.S. I have updated the tags for the question. Review and accept them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to come from :-
`Illegal char``at index 7: ..\..\l?brary_man?fest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`
i.e.:- l`?`brary_man`?`fest the ? mark in the project folder names.
I followed the path you had written in one of my projects that was using react-native-fbsdk
path:- \node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build\intermediates\lıbrary_manıfest\debug

but in my project there was no mistake in any of the "i"s in the folder names.

[image]

I can only suggest you to delete the node_modules folder and `npm install` the modules.

BTW i am using "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0" version.
Hope it will help you.

If it does not work, i think the problem is with your Android Studio.
It is not building the project properly.
Try updating it.

Update:- It seems that it is a problem that arises in Visual Studio.
Please check the link:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258530/11129555

Comment: Turns out the problem is about the library_manifest issue indeed, my computer's language is set as Turkish, and in Turkish there are two different letter "I"s. "I"s lowercase counterpart is "ı" and "i"s uppercase counterpart is "İ". After changing my computer's display language to English and restarting the computer I deleted node_modules and npm installed in the project and now it works.

Comment: I assume when installing react-native-fbsdk files there is a conversion from uppercase to lowercase for the filenames and this is the root of the problem. Surely enough the "library_manifest" in the same file path has "i"s in it now in the working version.

Comment: npm says :- You can’t create new packages with upper-case letters in the name any more, but packages with upper-case letters in their names are still in the registry and still in use.
What you say is correct......
do upvote the answer