# I press Ctrl + Alt + C then throw Error: Illegal character in path Illegal character in path

Tags: c#

**1.** I want to add new class then click on class.

[image]

**2.** then show Error:**Illegal character in path**

[image]

**3.** please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to name the class

Comment: What did you do between: clicking on "Add a new class" and the code written - AND the message box that appears? And also, which string did you enter, for what, where, how?

Comment: I press Ctrl + Alt + C  then throw Error: Illegal character in path Illegal character in path

Comment: Also when did you start receiving this error?? What changed between the time creating the class worked properly and now??

Comment: time creating the class then throw Illegal character in path Illegal character in path

Comment: It could be a number of things, including a buggy Visual Studio extension or the location where you saved your solution contains foreign characters in path. Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228752/visual-studio-build-error-illegal-characters-in-path).

Comment: these error comeing from  yesterday .

Comment: try to search for what characters are illegal when naming a class

Comment: @PankajKumar If VS is corrupted, try to [repair](https://docs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio) it, else uninstall & reinstall, else do a [full cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors/62713351#62713351), else reinstall Windows. Also do you do a daily incremental backup using for example O&O DiskImage or Macrium Reflect? Thus do a restore at the last known good stats, and restore by hand your working files changes (User folder) or using before Windows export, and after, user data import.

Comment: @PankajKumar Also, have you also restarted Windows and/or checked the Windows keyboard settings? Have you tried to **Reset VS settings to defaults** in case of keyboard shortcuts settings has been corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Class file name might have illegal characters like single quote, double quote, tilt etc. Because of that you are seeing that error. Avoid special characters and symbols.
Try to use Alpha & numeric characters as class names or file names while adding using visual studio.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge & experience. But your answer has a low quality. Sometimes a comment or a flag/close may be more relevant. To help you improve your answersplease read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [How do I write a good answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) & [Answering technical questions helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully).

Comment: I press Ctrl + Alt + C then throw Error: Illegal character in path Illegal character in path