Visual Studio 2022 doesn't create a new (asp.net vue, react) project
For some reason, Vue projects with asp.net and react with asp.net are not created.

Swears at unacceptable signs on the way, although there are no such signs on the way. Tried reinstalling VS, changing paths, didn't help.


Post your project file path. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228752/visual-studio-build-error-illegal-characters-in-path

It looks like it, but it's not the same. This happens to me when creating a JS Vue and React project.

My colleague met this before.
Open your Powershell and run this command $env:path >> C:\env.txt.
Open this file to view the contents of the path environment variable and check if any Illegal characters in the contents like quotations.

When you reply to me, you can bring the file and screenshots

And the path was fine too... It came to completely reinstall Windows and all dependencies. And now everything works as it should.
